# After intiallizing FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have called Fancy-Box **($('.modalBox').fancybox();)** to show a table on the overlay,  but after it has loaded i would like to add class.
How do i detect that Fancy-box has finished loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Use event `onComplete`:

```
$(".modalBox").fancybox({
    onStart : function() {
    },
    onCancel : function() {
    },
    onComplete : function() {
    },
    onCleanup : function() {
    },
    onClosed : function() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below logic

$('.modalBox').fancybox({  
  onComplete: addClassFunction
});

//call back function 
function addClassFunction{ 
    /* Write your code here */ 
}